# Facebook iframe tab app that's visible to all, but the app is not publically available?

Tags: facebook, iframe, private

To the best of my knowledge so far, it's possible to create your own facebook app to drop a custom tab and iframed content onto your page. I've run through a few basic steps to test, but here's my problem:

I'm creating a custom facebook landing page for a specific purpose, and I don't want that app to just be available for anyone to install. However, with that app installed on my page, I want everyone to be able to see the content. I tried turning 'sandbox' on but that hides the app AND the content.

I haven't found a pre-made iframe wrapper that meets all my needs. Of all the tutorials I've read and searched for, I haven't seen anybody mention concerns with keeping their app out of the public's hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is easy, parse [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) and see if you app is accessed via Page or directly via apps.facebook.com, if the second one is true, just redirect user to your Facebook Page Tab.

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

$signed_request = $_POST['signed_request'];
$response = parse_signed_request($signed_request);

if(empty($response['page']['id'])){
            die('<script>top.location.href = your_page_tab_url</script>');  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the concept here but where would this code go? In my fb app itself? I'm completely new to this.

Comment: Yes, in your index.php (or whatever it is), just copy-paste this code above, should work... remember to change your_page_tab_url to real one :)

Comment: If I need this to work in an asp.net page, would I need to get it rewritten? This is PHP, correct?

Comment: Yeah, but I guess it is easy.